# JavaScript mask money doesn't work after adding another input in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, money-format

I am new in JavaScript and jQuery, and I have a problem when I use the mask money plugin. It worked well, but when I make some JavaScript to add another input in table, the new row doesn't work with the maskmoney even though it had the same class

Here's my table:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td width="100"><center>Waqaf</center></td>
        <td width="100"><center>Operasional Sekolah</center></td>
        <td width="100"><center>Seragam</center></td>
    </tr>  
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="waqaf" id=""></td>
        <td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="operasional_sekolah" id=""></td>
        <td width="100"><input type="text" class="form-control price" name="seragam" id=""></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The JS for adding new field was running well, when I've checked the inspect element outputing input with same class. And the problem is in the plugin JS mask money

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.price').number( true, 2 );
</script>
```

(see picture below)

[image]

BUT when I manually make another text input it worked well

[image]

Why doesn't it work even though I make another field with js event with same input and class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do  $('input.price').number( true, 2 ); each time a new row is created, the method currently only applies to the first row.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this plugin](https://github.com/plentz/jquery-maskmoney/blob/master/src/jquery.maskMoney.js), then it's important to know it uses [$.bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) to handle events. It means that new inputs won't be handled in any way by this plugin. Today we should use [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for this kind of bindings (and '$.live' in early versions of jQuery).